# React-Native ListView: cannot read property of undefined

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am using SQLite as the device's database. What I am trying to basically achieve is this:

1- Give a user the ability to star his favorite "data"

2- Once the data gets saved in the db, retrieve it inside another page and insert them into a listView for the user to see at any time.

But no matter how much I try, I am always getting the same error.

**Cannot read property of undefined.**

The code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  View,
  Text,
  ListView
} from 'react-native'
var SQLite = require('react-native-sqlite-storage')
var db = SQLite.openDatabase({ name: "RHPC.db", location: "default"})
var obj;

class Schedules extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
            rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
        });

    this.state = {
      datasource: []
    }

    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM schedules", [], (tx, res) => {
        let len = res.rows.length;
        if(len > 0) {
          for(let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var obj = [{id: res.rows.item(i)["id"], title: res.rows.item(i)["title"]}]
          }
          this.setState({
            datasource: obj
          })
        } else {
          console.log("empty")
        }
      })
    }, (err) => {
      console.log("error: " + JSON.stringify(err))
    })
  }

  _renderRow(rowData) {
    return(
      <View>
        <Text key={rowData.id}>
          {rowData.title}
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.datasource);
    return(
      <View style={{marginTop: 150}}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.datasource}
          renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const styles = {

}

export default Schedules;
```

When I try to console.log the dataSource state:

```
0: Object
id: 2
title: "Session 1: Transition from Humanitarian Assistance to Rebuilding Health & Health Systems."
```

So in other words it looks like it's working but not 100%? Because I do have two rows inside that table and it's only retrieving the last one. Is this the cause of the undefined issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `ListView` in a wrong way, you create new dataSource in constructor (`ds`) and not assign it anywhere, checkout example in documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html

It should be:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
     dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2}),
    }
}
```

And in setState make something like this:

```
this.setState({
    datasource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(obj)
})
```

#### Edit:

And in your `for` loop you should have:

```
var obj = [];
for(let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    obj.push({id: res.rows.item(i)["id"], title: res.rows.item(i)["title"]});
}
```

Comment: Kind of fixed the issue but it's still showing the last data only

Comment: Because in your `for` loop you overwrite the `obj`, I added `Edit` to answer with proper code.